# Не работает if после input

Tags: python

Не работает if после input,
если после инпута поставить просто print, то он работает, а if - нет

```
ab = {  "Мама" : "890878xxx07",
        "Папа" : "890878xxt07"
}


print("Выберите действие:")
print("1)Добавить контакт")
print("2)Удалить контакт")
print("3)Просмотреть список всех контактов")
print("4)Изменить контакт")
print("5)Найти контакт")

act = input("Действие: ")

if act == 3:
    print("fgf")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Результат работы функции `input` - это строка. Вы сравниваете строку `3` и число `3`. Поэтому ваше условие не выполняется.

Нужно либо сравнивать со строкой: `act == '3'`, либо привести строку к числу `int(act) == 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Надо так

```
act = int(input("Действие"))
```

Comment: Ты бог, благодарю)